# How would I create an instance method with private variables?

Tags: javascript

I am working through "JavaScript Web Applications" an want to append the class library I created. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andrewjmead/gXMp8/. Right now it works, but I remember hearing it is best to avoid using __proto__ in your code. I am currently using this to create functions to manipulate private variables.

Right now the Cat class inherits from the Animal class. I want to add a private variable "name" in the constructor for cat and then create a getName and setName to manipulate this value for each instance.

```
Var tom = Cat("tom");
tom.setName("fud");
tom.getName(); //fud
```

Should I be using this.getName() instead of this.**proto**.getName(), or am I wrong altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in dynamic languages like javscript, or Python, there are no needs for really `private` variables. When we say something `private`, we actually say "Don't touch this stuff if you don't know what you are doing". So don't be too strict about the `private` thing. And, if you really want to keep some variables `private`, I prefer using `closure`. it is a good approach to make some variable really `private`. For example:

```
function Cat(name){
    var _name = name;

    this.getName = function(){
        return _name;
    }

    this.setName = function(name){
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

In this approach, there is no way to access the `_name` variable out of `Cat`. But there are drawbacks you can easily figure out, that you have to write your `getter` and `setter` methods inside of `constructor` function. The fancy `Cat.prototype.someFunc` declaration gone.

In my real work, I used to work with javascript for 2 years, I am favor of using the leading `_` to tell others, this is a private variable, cause I am a Python fan. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I don't really need privacy in this example. I just wanted to know how exactly it could be done. Thanks for the informative answer.

Comment: Yes, the truly private variable only can be done via closure.